# FluentBit in GKE Autopilot or alternatives?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fluent-bit

I'm migrating my cluster to GKE using autpilot mode, and I'm trying to apply fluentbit for logging (to be sent to Elasticsearch and then Kibana to be alerted on a slack channel).

But it seems that GKE Autopilot doesn't want me to do anything on the `hostPath` other than reading into files inside `/var/log` according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#host_options_restrictions). However Fluentbit needs to access `/var/lib/docker/containers` which is different from `/var/log` and also access to write inside `/var/log`

Is there a way to get around this or how do you usually log in GKE Autopilot with alerts?
Experience sharing is also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the official documentation:

> #### External monitoring tools
>
> Most external monitoring tools require access that is restricted. Solutions from several Google Cloud partners are available for use on Autopilot, however not all are supported, and **custom monitoring tools cannot be installed on Autopilot clusters.**
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Autopilot overview: External monitoring tools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#external_monitoring_tools)*
>
> ---
>
> #### Host options restrictions
>
> HostPort and hostNetwork are not permitted because node management is handled by GKE. Using [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volumes in write mode is prohibited, **while using hostPath volumes in read mode is allowed only for `/var/log/` path prefixes**. Using [host namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces) in workloads is prohibited.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Autopilot overview: Host options restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#host_options_restrictions)*

As you've already found the access to the `/var/lib/docker/containers` directory is not possible with the `GKE` in `Autopilot` mode.

As a **workaround** you could try to **either**:

- Use `GKE` cluster in `standard` mode.
- Use `Cloud Operations` with its Slack notification channel. You can read more about this topic by following:

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Monitoring: Alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts)*
  - *[Cloud.google.com: Monitoring: Support: Notification options: Slack](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#slack)*

I'd reckon you could also consider checking the guide for exporting logs to `Elasticsearch` from `Cloud Logging`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Architecture: Scenarios for exporting Cloud Logging: Elasticsearch](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/exporting-stackdriver-logging-elasticsearch)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Prometheus on GKE Autopilot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67599710/12257134)*