# metrics-server on gke autopilot

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I am using GKE autopilot cluster, and I am trying to get prometheus metrics for the CPU and memory usages of my pods/containers.
As far as I know metrics-server is installed by default on any GKE cluster.
I can also see it in the pods list in the kube-system namespace:

> kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-94768
> 1/1     Running   0             72m kube-system
> gke-metrics-agent-hvpb7                                    1/1
> Running   0             7h29m kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-j9lcl
> 1/1     Running   0             74m kube-system
> gke-metrics-agent-jfqkc                                    1/1
> Running   0             72m kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-qwnxf
> 1/1     Running   0             75m kube-system
> gke-metrics-agent-rz6t5                                    1/1
> Running   0             3m27s kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-wzqhc
> 1/1     Running   0             7h26m

But, I do not see any CPU and memory metrics for the pods/containers.
I cannot install metrics-server myself since in the autopilot mode, the kube-system namespace is protected by permissions.

How can I get pods/container memory and CPU metrics to prometheus in GKE autopilot?

Comment: Are you looking to run your own Prometheus installation or are you just trying to use Grafana to display the metrics?

Comment: I am running my own prometheus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus on GKE Autopilot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595875/prometheus-on-gke-autopilot)